# Three Right Triangles

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, geometry

There are three special right triangles, all of their edge lengths are positive integers.

One of the triangles' *longer leg*, the other triangle's *shorter leg* and *hypotenuse* of the last triangle are all ***equal to each other***.

> What is the least value of the shortest hypotenuse among these triangles?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is:

> 15

it can be found in these triangles:

> 9 12 15
>  8 15 17
>  15 20 25

note that:

> two of these are scalings of the smallest triangle possible, the 3 4 5

Why smaller numbers do not work:

> the smallest possible hypotenuses less than 15 are: 5, and 10, 13. 5 can only ever be in the hypotenuse, as it is so small. for 10 and 14, here are all the possible triangles with them:
>
>  10:
>
>  10 24 26
>  6 8 10
>
>  13:
>  5 12 13
>  13 84 89

as you can see:

> none of these can be in the larger leg

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick proof that numbers less than

> 15

don't work.

> 9 12 15
>
>  8 15 17
>
>  15 20 25 means 15 works as noted in micsthepick's answer

**No more spoilers from here on - read at your own peril**

The [formula for primitive pythagorean triples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple#Generating_a_triple) is actually quite well-known. Now, that means that the largest number in a triple can be expressed as a multiple of a sum of squares, so that means the answer, if less than 15, is either 5,10 or 13.

### 5

$5^2+1^2=26$ is not a square

$5^2+2^2=29$ is not a square

$5^2+3^2=34$ is not a square

$5^2+4^2=41$ is not a square

### 10

$10^2+1^2=101$ is not a square

$10^2+2^2=104$ is not a square

$10^2+3^2=109$ is not a square

$10^2+4^2=116$ is not a square

$10^2+5^2=125$ is not a square

$10^2+6^2=136$ is not a square

$10^2+7^2=149$ is not a square

$10^2+8^2=164$ is not a square

$10^2+9^2=181$ is not a square

### 13

$13^2+1^2=170$ is not a square

$13^2+2^2=173$ is not a square

$13^2+3^2=178$ is not a square

$13^2+4^2=185$ is not a square

$13^2+5^2=194$ is not a square

$13^2+6^2=205$ is not a square

$13^2+7^2=218$ is not a square

$13^2+8^2=233$ is not a square

$13^2+9^2=250$ is not a square

$13^2+10^2=269$ is not a square

$13^2+11^2=290$ is not a square

$13^2+12^2=313$ is not a square